# samba access from win98

Tags: samba, windows

the admin installed a new file server in our institute:
OpenSuse 11.1 with Samba 3.2.7-11.3.2-2154-SUSE-CODE11.
They copied the smb.conf from the old machine (hosting Samba 3.0.0) to the new one.

Everything works as before, but **one Windows 98 machine can see but not access the file server**. It prompts for user authentication, but will not accept any user-password combination.

There exists a lot of discussion about the problem on the net, but none provided a clear answer to the problem.

EDIT:

1. I changed Win98 registry enable plain-text passwords, and alternatively
   changed server's smb.conf and /etc/smbpasswd to accept encrypted passwords
2. Further I provide a profile with a user-password combination on Win98 machine similar to one of the samba users-password combinations.
3. I changed smb.conf such that the samba server is the Local Master Browser

All these changes are not necessary when using the older samba server. So, I conclude that a configuration problem on the server side is likely.

If you need any further information, I will post them here.

Best regards,
Simon

Answer (score 2):

Save the world from bad password protocols, and install the Active Directory Client Extensions for Windows 98 onto the client. It enables a wider, and vastly more secure, suite of password protocols that Samba 3.2 also supports. Two articles:

How to enable NTLMv2 on Win98:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239869

How to get the Client Extensions:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288358/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting "lanman auth = YES" (without "") in the [global] section of the smb.conf?
And try with "pdbedit -L username" if the user isn't locked out. (He is, when pdbedit shows only XXX for the password.)
If so, set the password again with smbpasswd.

OH yeah.. And put "lanman auth = YES" as the first option directly AFTER the [global] to make it work permanently.

Oh and maybe "client lanman auth = YES" must be set too in your config.